# How to make View Controller Animated When called in App Delegate

Tags: ios, swift

I am dismissing the login view controller from the AppDelegate.swift file. but the view controller just vanishes off the screen when i run the below code, how can i have the view controller slide down.

```
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

    if currentUser != nil {
        var dashVC = mainSB.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("dashView") as! itsTimeDashVC
        window!.rootViewController = dashVC
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }
```

Comment: You need animation or you want to just solve Black screen issue before root view appear?

Comment: just the animation, there is no issue with black screen. everything works fine, just that that login screen just vanishes without a animation.

Comment: Try Stage 3: Shrink-Wrapping from this link http://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/custom-container-view-controller-transitions/

Comment: let me try it out, thanks. would you know a swift version of it?

Comment: No, i have to convert it by my self :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating root view with animation, May be that should work. I do not have tried it :

```
UIView.transitionFromView(self.window.rootViewController.view, toView: viewController.view, duration:0.6, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil), completion: { (fininshed: Bool) -> () in

self.window.rootViewController = viewController

})
```